# LinqToTwitter - IsAuthorized always returns false for ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have an `MVC4` web application that uses `LinqToTwitter` to display Tweets when a user's profile page is visited, if they have a Twitter handle.

For this I use ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer:

```
var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
{
  Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
  {
    ConsumerKey = "twitterConsumerKey",
    ConsumerSecret = "twitterConsumerSecret"
  }
};
auth.Authorize();
```

My problem is that I have found that `auth.IsAuthorized` always returns false, even when I have call `Authorize()` and am successfully able to make calls to Twitter. And also, I have found that if I call `Authorize()` in every call made to Twitter, that an unhandled exception is thrown if I repeat the call enough times.

It seems quite important that I am able to know if auth is authorized before I make the call to Twitter. For now, I have put in a quick fix where I store my own `IsAuthorized Session` variable - but am not sure how reliable this is, because the `Session` variable could outlive the actual authentication itself?

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you authorize, Twitter will return a bearer token. After Authorize, you can grab this from the auth.BearerToken property. On subsequent calls, you can re-use the same bearer token. The bearer token doesn't expire, unless you invalidate it. Twitter's recommendation is that you use the bearer token for about 15 minutes and then re-authorize after that.

Comment: For whatever reason I get BasicToken and not a BearerToken, and IsAuthorized is always false for me. Then I get "Bad Authentication data" with a inner exception containing "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.", any ideas?

Comment: @Oakcool Your situations sounds almost like a 401. I have a FAQ here: https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @FurquanKhan One of the reasons for a 403 is if you try to use ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer in the context of a user. e.g. it's fine for search because that isn't associated with a user. However, if you used it to tweet, that wouldn't work because tweeting is something that a specific user does. So, you should look at one of the other authorizers.

Comment: @JoeMayo Refer to this link and see my comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156357/using-linq2twitter-and-cached-oauth-tokens-withing-a-servicestack-api