# C# - LINQ to Twitter - Read twitter landing page without login

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I just started making a application that uses information from twitter. I want to get the posts that are available on the [Twitter landing page](http://twitter.com) when no user is logged in. This page shows public posts that might be relevant to your geo location. Is it possible to get these posts using [LinqToTwitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter) without logging in a user?

Comment: You are asking for an [application-only](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) authentication, that is not the typical approach to Twitter API. Anyway it looks like a **duplicate** question. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387037/twitter-api-application-only-authentication-with-linq2twitter

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer. I wont be looking at this till next thursday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Authentication without user context

As per my comment, this is called [application-only](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) authentication, and the [documentation](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Application-Only-Authorization) of LinqToTwitter about it actually mentions this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16390303/6298965) of Joe Mayo that I've already suggested you to follow.

### Geolocation

Finally, look at this [doc](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Searching-Twitter) for the `GeoCode`: something like what was done in this [post](https://m.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/3o44ou/20_for_a_twitter_search_example/)

```
var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
{
    Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
    {
        ConsumerKey = [ConsumerKey],
        ConsumerSecret = [ConsumerSecret]
    }
};

auth.Authorize();

var _twitterContext = new TwitterContext(auth);

var srch =
    (from search in _twitterContext.Search
     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
           search.Query == "twitter" &&
           search.Count == 7 &&
           search.GeoCode == "51.507351,-0.127758,1km"
     select search)
    .SingleOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("\nQuery: {0}\n", srch.SearchMetaData.Query);
srch.Statuses.ForEach(entry =>
    Console.WriteLine(
        "ID: {0, -15}, Source: {1}\nContent: {2}\n",
        entry.StatusID, entry.Source, entry.Text));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is a very good way to emulate the twitter homepage. I have taken the center geolocation of my country with the maximum radius of my country. I also added `search.ResultType == Twitter.ResultType.Popular`.